# data.gov GIOVANNI Portal Data Missing

Tags: data.gov

I am not able to find the some data sets on the new GIOVANNI portal.
Sample file names of the data I had downloaded a year ago from the portal are given below. I am not able to find same file names or file names which match description.

TRMM_3B43_ACC.007_20141101_000000.G3.txt
GLDAS_NOAH10_M.001.soilm4.201404.G3.input.txt
GLDAS_NOAH10_M.001.swe.200205.G3.input.txt

Comment: can you provide more details...particular url? just data.gov? what are you searching for? also what is the value of the search you are performing on data.gov?